# Quotations / examples in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I was wondering if there is any way to write something like a quotation or a motto in org mode, in a way that is differentiated from the rest of the text. For instance, it could be indented with a specific number of spaces, and has some sort of "padding" from the rest of the text. Thank you.

Comment: See:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9g2ghj/orgemphasisregexpcomponents_explanation/ ... specifically, `(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("\"[^\"]*\"" . 'org-special-keyword)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Orgmode way to write quotations are quotation blocks:

```
#+begin_quote
This is quoted stuff. Org /formatting/ does work here.
#+end_quote
```

In HTML export uses the `<blockquote>` tag for such blocks. You can define the style in `org-html-head` if you like.

Comment: As explained in the org-mode documentation: https://orgmode.org/manual/Paragraphs.html#Paragraphs